# Vscode, python segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with vscode and python. I created simple python script which works with python3 interpreter and then run it using python3 test.py, which is fine.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Ts = 0.01
t = np.arange(-5, 5, Ts)

y = t**2
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

But when I try to run it using vscode debug I get a segmentation fault(core dumped).

```
agentdenton@agentdenton-latitude:~/dev/Test/numpy_test$ python3 test.py 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Which is weird because same code works fine on my VM with same Ubuntu. I wonder if I doing something wrong here or is it bug?
I'm using ubuntu 19.04 and latest version of vscode also python 3.7.5. Error happens only if I import some module and execute function from it, with regular python code it works fine.
Thank you for your attention and sorry for bad english skills!

Comment: Are the two environments exactly the same? And how are you using the debugger because there should be a bunch more in the command-line if you're executing under the debugger.

Comment: Yeah. they almost same, it`s standart configutarion generated by vscode.

Comment: I have the same issue, waiting for an answer!

Comment: And to double check, you're using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python, correct?

Comment: Yes, I using python from marketplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probability the VS code polluted the python enviroment. You can uninstall the python enviroment and reinstall a new clean enviroment. If you use conda, you can update the enviroment by `conda update --all`.